# "Fellers", what does it mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, syntax

In what sense is "fellers" used here and what is the subject to the predicate "was wanting"? The subject is Jennie, but she doesn't have a wife. Wells's short story The Purple Pileus

> Then Jennie came in as a female Mephistopheles, a gabbling chronicle of "**fellers**," and **was always** wanting his wife to go to theatres and "all that."

Comment: Re *but she doesn't have a wife*. Reading the [paragraph](http://www.telelib.com/authors/W/WellsHerbertGeorge/prose/plattnerstory/purplepileus.html) shows that "his wife" refers to Coombes's wife. Jennie wants to go to the theatre with Coombes's wife. I guess that "fellers" is a colloquial way of saying "fellows".

Comment: I am not from the British isles. But from movies I have seen, "fellers" may be more common in Irish and Scottish dialects of English. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @banuyayi - it was normal in 1896 London, and still is now.

Comment: Jenny, in Mr Coombes' opinion, talks too much ('gabbing'), and for too long ('chronicle') about such things as 'fellers' (fellows, men) and keeps wanting Mrs Coombes to go to theatres and 'all that' (i.e. other activities which are frivolous in Mr Coombes' eyes).

Comment: Beware of interpreting Wells' sarcasm against 1896 petty-bourgeois manners, and the 1896 language, as if they were modern.

Comment: @banuyayi - 'Feller' is common as an informal pronunciation of 'fellow' all over England.

Comment: "a female Mephistopheles, a gabbling chronicle of "fellers" could translate as "a free spirit who brags about her conquests." @MichaelHarvey [alludes](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/324383/fellers-what-does-it-mean-in-this-sentence#comment611035_324383) to the mores of the time, and using [Mephistopheles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mephistopheles) is quite pejorative.